# No instances in NServiceBus Performance Counters

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

I've tried everything I can think of but I can't get NServiceBus performance counters to work.

NServiceBus version: 3.2.8

I've installed the Performance Counters using the NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.PerformanceCounterInstaller from the 3.2.8 NServiceBus.Core assembly and they are visible in Performance Monitor, but I can't get any instances to appear.

I've tried running NServiceBus.Host.exe from an elevated command prompt using the NServiceBus.Production & NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters profiles. I added my user account to the Performance Monitor Users security group, although I'm already a local admin.
I passed some messages through the service.

But I just can't get any performance counter instances...

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you installed the endpoint as a service? That's typically when installers are run.

Comment: Take a look [at Andreas's blog:](http://andreasohlund.net/2012/01/26/installers-in-nservicebus-3-0/)
And in the [NServiceBus documentation site here:](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/more-on-profiles)

Comment: I tried installing as a service and running from command line. Both with the NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters profile. I've also looked through Andreas' blog and other sources I can find but still no instances appearing...